# Access class variable to another class in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

> Kotlin : below i have this code I got the value of 'strinrec' by calling this..
> problem is how i access 'stringrec' value in another class (say class B)

```
class  adapter_comm_recver(){

fun priiint(editTInput: String){
    val stringrec = editTInput
    Log.e("tag1",stringrec)//to see it works
}
```

}

Comment: get familair with [companion object](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/object-declarations.html#companion-objects)

Comment: You must also pass an instance of class B to your function so you can access its members. Add another parameter to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the rest of your code looks, the easiest way would probably be to either return stringrec from priiint, or store the value as a class member in your first class.

```
class  adapter_comm_recver(): String{
   var stringrec = ""

   fun priiint(editTInput: String) {
       val stringrec = editTInput
       Log.e("tag1",stringrec)//to see it works

       this.stringrec = stringrec

       return stringrec
   }
}

class B() {
   val adapter = adapter_comm_recver()

   val stringAsReturn = adapter.priint()
   val stringAsMember = adapter.stringrec
   
}
```